# Numeric limits in stanza

Tags: numeric-limits, stanza

In stanza, I would like to get the numeric limits (min and max) of Int and Double types.
In C++, there are `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`, `DBL_MIN` and `DBL_MAX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following special constants are declared in `core`.

```
BYTE-MAX
BYTE-MIN
INT-MAX
INT-MIN
LONG-MAX
LONG-MIN
FLOAT-MAX
FLOAT-MIN-NORMAL
FLOAT-MIN
FLOAT-NAN
FLOAT-POSITIVE-INFINITY
FLOAT-NEGATIVE-INFINITY
DOUBLE-MAX
DOUBLE-MIN-NORMAL
DOUBLE-MIN
DOUBLE-NAN
DOUBLE-POSITIVE-INFINITY
DOUBLE-NEGATIVE-INFINITY
```

Patrick